# AngularJS Directive - detect if scrolling has stopped and execute a function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In angularjs directive how do you detect if the user has stopped scrolling.

```
.directive('scrollable', ['$document', '$window', function ($document, $window, ) { 
return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $document.bind('scroll', function() {

            // detect if scroll has stop and execute a function        
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to detect it manually after some time for example 250ms :-

```
 $document.bind('scroll', function() {
clearTimeout( $.data( this, "scrollCheck" ) );
                $.data( this, "scrollCheck", setTimeout(function() {
                    //Here you can call a function after scroll stopped
                }, 250) );      
        });
```

**UPDATE**:-

Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Jok5yW8h6F8bzgyCUOd?p=preview)